# SQL server use "IF variable LIKE pattern"

Tags: sql-server

Why this doesn't work?

```
DECLARE @str varchar = '######'

IF @str LIKE '%###%' SELECT 1
```

but this works

```
IF '######' LIKE '%###%' SELECT 1
```

**UPDATE**

why this works

```
DECLARE @Comment varchar(255) = '[A-B-C-D]'

IF @Comment LIKE '%[%-%-%-%]%' SELECT 1
```

however this doesn't work?

```
DECLARE @Comment nvarchar(255) = '[A-B-C-D]'

IF @Comment LIKE '%[%-%-%-%]%' SELECT 1
```

Comment: Regarding your edit see https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/742841/pattern-syntax-undocumented-difference-in-behaviour-between-varchar-vs-nvarchar

Answer (score 4):

Add to your variable type length.

```
DECLARE @str varchar = '######'

IF @str LIKE '%###%' SELECT 1
```

is the same as (implicit cast will change it to '#')

```
DECLARE @str varchar(1) = '######'

/* IF '#' LIKE '%###%' SELECT 1 */
IF @str LIKE '%###%' SELECT 1
```

This will work:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(20) = '######'

IF @str LIKE '%###%' SELECT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

try declaring the size of your varchar

```
DECLARE @str varchar(50) = '######'

SELECT 1 WHERE  @str LIKE '%###%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use specify type length, it will use mimimum code page length.This contants, varchar 1 and nvarchar 2. So, actually if scope is working normaly.

```
DECLARE @str varchar = '######'
SELECT  DATALENGTH(@str) 

DECLARE @str1 varchar(20) = '######'
select DATALENGTH(@str1) 

DECLARE @str3 nvarchar = '######'
SELECT  DATALENGTH(@str3) 

DECLARE @str4 nvarchar(20) = '######'
select DATALENGTH(@str4)
```

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks @LuFFy, i fixing now.